# selenium web driver form submission

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, form-submit

I am facing an issue with the select options that aren't loading on page load and click button that sends XHR.

(all these functionalities are working fine when using a browser, just using selenium these issues are surfacing)

is it possible that certain scripts aren't loading? if yes how to overcome that apart from using web driver wait or hard sleep, because these aren't solving my issues.

or is it possible that the server denying the request as I am using selenium to request data??

tried both for chrome n firefox same issue exists

---

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
    class firefoxT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\C USERS DATA\\geckodriver.exe" );

         
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette",true);
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

         
    driver.navigate().to("url");


driver.manage().window().maximize();

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,600)");
try{
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
 js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#subtab-equity > div > div.more_info_container > nav > div > div > a:nth-child(5)\").click()");
 try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
 }catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
 }
 js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#historical-trade > section > div > div.block-detail-dates-box > div > div.col-md-5 > ul > li:nth-child(6) > a\").click()");
 try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
 }catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
 }
 js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#historical-trade > section > div > div.histo-data-block > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.custom_select_bs.greybrdr > div > button > span\").innerText=\"EQ\"");
 
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#historical-trade > section > div > div.histo-data-block > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.col-md-6.col-6.text-right > div > a\").click()");

driver.quit();
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your code to your post? Are you running headless selenium?

Comment: not headless n yes added above

Comment: @user2230604 try to run this script in the incognito mode of the browser